# SetWindowsHookEx fails with error 126

Tags: c#, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to use the [Gma.UserActivityMonitor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) library in a project and I've faced an error I can not overcome on my own.

In the `HookManager.Callbacks.cs` file there's a static method called `EnsureSubscribedToGlobalMouseEvents` with the following code (more or less):

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0];
var mar = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(asm);
s_MouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
    WH_MOUSE_LL,
    s_MouseDelegate,
    mar,
    0);
//If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
if (s_MouseHookHandle == 0)
{
    //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    //do cleanup

    //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
}
```

The `SetWindowsHookEx` always returns `0` and the above code keeps throwing an exception with message `The specified module could not be found` and the call to `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` returns code `126`. I can successfully run the demo provided with Gma.UserActivityMonitor's original project but since my project is a little too complicated to explain here I can not go into detail explaining its difference with mine. I'm just hoping someone can blind guess the problem.

BTW, in the project's FAQ it's said that others have a problem close to mine (with `SetWindowsHookEx` returning error) when the `Enable Visual Studio hosting process` is checked only when the project is debugged. So I unchecked that box in mine and still I'm having the same problem, and not just in debugging mode but also when I double click the release file in Windows Explorer (no Visual Studio involved).

To give more information, in demo project (which works fine) the `asm` variable points to `{Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll}` and the same in my project which the exception is thrown!

Comment: it might be related to bitness of the processes involved...

Comment: Could you please explain more or point me to the right resource?

Comment: Hooking usually involves some code becoming part of the target process(es). This can be achieved in different ways but basically any difference in bitness regarding your process, the hooked process(es) and the OS can lead to problems and/or erratci behaviour.

Comment: Could you please tell me what can I do in this case? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no easy fix - it depends on what you want to achieve... best "first step" would be to really read up on hooking, bitness, permissions etc. - this will give you a much clearer picture so you can post questions which are much more specific... and in turn lead to helpful answers.

Comment: For this specific library it might help to change the source code (for details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774741/module-not-found).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This kind of code does not work anymore on .NET 4 and up.  The error code you get is otherwise descriptive, 126 = "The specified module could not be found".  Which tells you that the "mar" variable contains junk.

.NET 4 had a pretty significant CLR change, it no longer pretends that jitted code lives inside unmanaged modules.  So Marshal.GetHINSTANCE() does not work anymore.  The code then gets sloppy, it forgets to check the return value, testing it for (IntPtr)-1 is required to detect failure and declare disaster.  Pretty common for code you find at Codeproject, lots of bugs and sloppiness that can't be fixed by contributors.  Not the SO model :)

SetWindowsHookEx() is a bit awkward for the low-level hooks.  It requires a valid module handle, and checks it, but doesn't actually use it.  This got fixed in Windows, somewhere around Win7 SP1.  While certainly intended to be a useful fix, it actually made the problem worse.  Because now it may work on your dev machine but not on your user's machine.

Anyhoo, the fix is simple, you just need to cough up a valid module handle.  You can get one from a module that is always present in a managed app, you'll need to [pinvoke LoadLibrary](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/LoadLibrary.html) to get it:

```
var mar = LoadLibrary("user32.dll");
s_MouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
    WH_MOUSE_LL,
    s_MouseDelegate,
    mar,
    0);
```

No need to call FreeLibrary(), that module stays loaded until your program terminates anyway.

Comment: Thanks Hans, it worked perfectly. I just want to add that I managed to find the problem. Yours will be the solution I will use but I just wanted to ask for your thoughts on my new discovery if you please. The problem was that my project's `Platform target` was set to x86 while my OS is Windows 7x64. Other choices like `x64` and `Any CPU` works on my machine but your solution works regardless of the `Platform target` so I'm going to go with that since I've got Win32 projects written in C++ in my solution. Do you think your solution is solid even in other OSs like WindowsXP, Vista or Windows 8?

Comment: I explicitly pointed out in the answer that making it work on any Windows version was the goal.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you SO much for posting this. I was about at wit's end with it... I was about to sell everything I own and move to the mountains.