# ExecutionEngineException on LowLevel Keyboard Hook

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, .net-5

I'm currently trying to get Global LowLevel keyboard hooks working in .net 5 with wpf, but after some time I always get an `ExecutionEngineException` and my App crashes. [According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.executionengineexception?view=net-5.0), this exception should never occur at all anymore, but for me it does. It is also not specific to my project, as a minimal WPF .net 5 project will also crash after some key mashing.

Has anyone any idea how to either fix it or get around this problem?

Example Code for the Main Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod,
        uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpFileName);


    private IntPtr _hook;


    public bool Hook() {
        if (_hook == IntPtr.Zero) {
            var modPtr = LoadLibrary("user32.dll");

            _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Handler, modPtr, 0);
        }

        return _hook != IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private IntPtr Handler(int code, IntPtr param, IntPtr lParam) {
        return CallNextHookEx(_hook, code, param, lParam);
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Hook();
    }
}
```

The Callstack I get:

```
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.IntPtr hwnd, int minMessage, int maxMessage)
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()
EngineExecutionError.dll!EngineExecutionError.App.Main()
```

Comment: Does .NET's default calling convention match the calling convention spelled out by the contract of the low-level keyboard hook API?

Comment: Also, what's the rationale behind passing the module handle of *user32.dll* as the 3rd argument to `SetWindowsHookEx`?

Comment: Rationale for user32.dll: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897646/setwindowshookex-fails-with-error-126/17898148#17898148

I had GetModuleHandle on the current module before with the same results, it "works" too so I didn't change it back

Comment: Both are wrong. Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw).

Comment: The default Calling convention is WinApi which refers to stdcall on windows which is the default for the win32 api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-160)

Comment: You can't have a .NET callback function that's not fixed in some way as .NET will move it when it wants. You should either use a GCHandle or make Handler static and build a reference on it (something like `static LowLevelKeyboardProc _handler = Handler` and use _handler, not Handler).

Comment: Well. if I set it to IntPtr.Zero the same thing happens. GetModuleHandle is called on the module that implements the handler; anyway, the KEYBOARD_LL should not need a module handle to the handler dll, because the handler is always called in the thread that registered it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)#remarks)

Comment: @SimonMourier looks like the GC was at fault here, totally forgot that... If you make an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: You should answer to correspond to your question exactly :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments, you should not pass a lambda or delegate directly into a Win32 Api call (or any C api call for that matter). The fix is either to make a static variable containing a reference to the function

```
private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _handler = Handler;
[...]
_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _handler, modPtr, 0);
```

or to pin the delegate, so the CLR won't move it around, which is what I opted for.

```
private LowLevelKeyboardProc _handler;
private GCHandle _gcHandler;

public KeyboardHook() {
    _handler = Handler;
    _gcHandler = GCHandle.Alloc(_handler);
}

[...]

_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _handler, modPtr, 0);
```

For the low level hooks, you seem to be able to set `modPtr` to either `LoadLibrary("user32.dll")`, `GetModuleHandle(null)` or `IntPtr.Zero`. Seems to work with all of them.